# Android Studio: Android 5 lollipop can't install and launch App

Tags: installation

I have 2 real android devices and I used them to test my android app (I am new at Android programing)
When I clicked "run" button, the dialog box showed me two of my devices:
Table 4.2.2 and Cellphone 5.0
After running, my tablet launched the app perfectly, but my phone (5.0) wouldn't launch, it even wouldn't install new app, I tried many time, and finally it run, but at the later time, I needed to remove previous app to run new app.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to remove the old version of your app all the time? If yes, you should use a keystore file for signing the app (and always the same). My device also refused to update an app because I didn't sign it with a keystore file. (I have one device with Android 5.1.1 and one with Android 4.2.2, had the same issue with the 5.1.1 one until I signed it)

Comment: Please tell me how to that?

Comment: @user3001833 Use google.com, search for "how to create keystore file for APK" and "how to sign an APK with a keystore file"

Comment: (The APK is signable with ZipSigner, because the APK is basically a ZIP file)

Comment: I very appreciate your help. And I just perceived it as  a situation to fix the problem. 
Long time passed but anyway can I know  why we need to create a siggned  apk?

Comment: @user3001833 It's because Android needs to check if the APK was made by the same developer/company. Signings can't be faked very easily, because the password you choose in your keystore file also changes the signing.